# Intent getStringExtra returning null

Tags: android, android-intent

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I have no idea where I went wrong..

So I sent some data through one activity and retrieving it from the other activity.

FirstActivity

```
Timber.i("Photo img : %s", posterUrl);
    String url = AppConstants.IMAGE_BASE_URL+ 
    AppConstants.POSTER_SIZE_ORIGINAL+ posterUrl;
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ImageFullActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(AppConstants.IMAGE_URL, url);
    startActivity(i);
```

Recieving Activity

```
Intent i = new Intent();
String imageUrl = i.getStringExtra(AppConstants.IMAGE_URL);    
Timber.i("GOt image url %s", imageUrl);
Picasso.with(this)
      .load(imageUrl)
      .into(image);
```

And I checked. I am not passing null through the extras. The posterUrl is a valid string.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `getIntent()` to get the intent instance that started the next activity as

```
 getIntent().getStringExtra
```

instead of creating a new empty one

```
//Intent i = new Intent(); remove

Intent i = getIntent(); // or do this
```

Comment: @SriramR i am glad that i could help, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//Intent i = new Intent();
String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra(AppConstants.IMAGE_URL);    
Timber.i("GOt image url %s", imageUrl);
Picasso.with(this)
      .load(imageUrl)
      .into(image);
```

**OR**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String imageUrl = bundle.getString(AppConstants.IMAGE_URL);
Timber.i("GOt image url %s", imageUrl);
Picasso.with(this)
      .load(imageUrl)
      .into(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra(AppConstants.IMAGE_URL);
```

You need to get the intent by getIntent() method

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are trying to `create new intent` in your receiving activity which does not have your data what you passed in other `activity`. 
To get the intent what you passed in other activity use `getIntent()`.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
```

Here this intent will be holding your data you passed from other activity.